# PHP require/include only works once in script then fails

Tags: php, include, require

This isn't a problem as such, but it's bugging me and I would appreciate any help. It might be totally obvious but I can't see it.

```
$root_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] 
require($root_path .'template/header.php')
require($root_path .'template/footer.php')
```

The script will include one or the other but not both. It will run and include the header but not the footer, if I swap them round it will load the footer first but not the header.

I've tried using `include` instead of `require` but get the same result.

It gives the error `allow_url_include = 0`. I know turning this one will solve it but my question is why is it happening? Why will it include one file but not the other? Is there any way to get them to both run without turning `allow_url_include` on (I'm trying to be security conscious). I have PHP 5.3 and am running WAMP. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Post minimal code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Can you show us the exact code causing this?

Comment: Please attach code examples. Is there any function, class, constant in your files? Or do they include any file that contain such definitions? (redefining them could be the problem) What is the error message?

Comment: try: `define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` then `require(ROOT_PATH .'template/header.php')` so that you can be sure that the variable is not being overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `$root_path` is changed in the file header.php or footer.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're redefining `$root_path` in the included file.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with what you've written. As the others have said, something is happening to `$root_path` or the script is terminating before it gets to that include.

Do a `var_dump($root_path)` right above the footer include. If that fires, you know it's getting to the include. If it still isn't working, do some echoes from within your footer to see if it gets inside the file.